# How can I double the size of every image on a web page?

Tags: javascript, css

There's a web page that I would like to double the size of all images on. I don't know any JavaScript or CSS. Can someone write me some code please? I tried this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'),function(i){
    i.width = i.width * 2;i.height = i.height * 2
});
```

But I don't know what I'm doing, and it's not working. Please help.

This is what the elements that I'm trying to double look like, if it's any help at all:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do something in GreaseMonkey or javascript console for a website which is already loaded in your browser? The code you already came up with should do the job if you paste in Browser's javascript console.

Comment: Greasemonkey. (or stylish) – this isn't really css but I stuck that in there anyway because it wouldn't let me just type “Greasemonkey.”.

Comment: What error are you facing? Probably your GreaseMonkey script isn't working at all. Try sticking in an alert or console.log statement.

Comment: Definitely a GreaseMonkey issue - works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/2c6s8/

Comment: I don't know how to do any of that, but I can tell it's working, because I set it to run everywhere and my gravatar logo on this page is twice the normal size. All other images are the same of course.

Comment: Also please be mindful that this won't touch the images which are background because of CSS property `background-image`. If one of your images are changing, and others are not, then its definitely because of other images are being added by CSS property `background-image`.

Comment: This is what the elements that I'm trying to double look like, if it's any help at all: http://puu.sh/1AEes

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. It makes EVERYTHING bigger, text, spacings and images. I use it in combo with NoSquint to reduce the text size again, but the spacing between posts and indentations and things is still screwed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Reference:** [**http://boards.4chan.org/g/**](http://boards.4chan.org/g/)

I've discovered an excellent feature that this website has for it's users, including built in customized viewing of their Thumbnail Images!

**The 4Chan Homepage Settings Menu**

That menu provides a whole lot of options to configure the webpage on how you see fit. I was astounded to see a `Custom CSS` feature that shows a `CSS Box` which will accept your own custom markup to tailor the site down to markup level! More on that in a bit.

First, I want to mention that they do provide **TWO** ready to use options that should satisfy your Thumbnail viewing requirements.

***Bounty EDIT:*** Users of the [**4chan-x Greasemonkey script**](http://mayhemydg.github.com/4chan-x/) already have these 2 options in **4chan Qt ≪Quality thumbnails≫ Settings** menu. Skip to the next EDIT below if your using this script.

Take a look at this screenshot that show 3 steps to perform, with step 2 being one or the other.

Right-click the image below and **view in full size** if that helps:

**`Open Image in New Tab / View Image`**

[image]

In **Step 1** above, notice that the `Settings` reflect the `4chan Homepage` and not the script.

In **Step 2a** above, this will closely reproduce the double image size for average images, but if those images are super large, they will use the available browsers width.

In **Step 2b** above, this choice instead will show a super large image if it exists up to the browsers width size.

If neither of these two ready-to-use thumbnail options suits your taste, keep reading.

Since your original goal is to see the thumbnails at twice the size, or `200%`, I analyzed the webpage to determine the most minimal settings required to show these Thumbnail Images at that size, but note many will be blurry at twice the size since the quality isn't increased. See Bounty EDIT below for solution for images that are not blurry at ANY size.

Having said that, you can choose `150%` to minimize the blur while still enlarging it, or choose the value that is acceptable to you if you did not want to use Greasemonkey.

---

**Bounty EDIT:**

The blurry images are no longer an issue when using these CSS Settings with [***4chan-x Greasemonkey Script***](http://mayhemydg.github.com/4chan-x/) to have **thumbnails twice the size**.

Note you will need to remove a default checkmark that is automatically applied for `Disable 4chan's extension` in the Greasemonkey Script, accessible by clicking the **4chan Qt ≪Quality thumbnails≫ Settings** link at the top-right corner of the webpage.

Once you exit that settings menu, enter the **4chan *Homepage* Settings Menu**. Remove **all** checkmarks, **except** for Custom CSS. To be sure, the image above did not remove all the checkmarks for which **4chan-x** recommends.

---

**Caution:** Using the *Custom CSS Settings* option can make the Settings Menu inaccessible! You'll need to use the browsers built in `inspect element` to make live changes on-the-fly to regain control.

The box below is not an image. Select, copy, and then paste this CSS into the Settings Menu CSS Box:

```css
div.file, a.fileThumb img {
  width: 200% !important;
  height: 200% !important;
  float: left; 
}

.fileInfo {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

To be clear, here's a screenshot of that box:
[image]

After you paste the above code into the `CSS Box`, press the `Save CSS Button` and ensure you have a `Checkmark` for `Custom CSS` and then press the `SAVE Button` to exit.

The page will then refresh itself with these new settings. Enjoy your 2x Thumbnails.

**Bounty EDIT:** Reminder that above image shows checkmarks in Essential section that should be removed. To be sure, the homepage top-right will have 4Chan's Original Settings Menu in middle:

> [4chan Qt ≪Quality thumbnails≫ Settings] **[Settings]** [Home]

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment previously, your code won't touch the images which are background images to non `<img>` html elements because of CSS property `background-image`.

So you need to run both your code to double `<img>` tags.

Also you need to set CSS property `background-size` to `200% Auto`.

Now ofcourse the question, is to what you want to add the css property. Chances are that all those images on 4chan are also links. So they must be anchor `<a>` tags with `background-image`.

Sorry I am in office, so I won't open up 4chan to confirm that.

But you can try this code in this same website:

```
$('a').css('background-size', '200% Auto');
```

My quick solution uses jQuery, but you get the idea.

**Update:**

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'),function(i){i.width = i.width * 2;i.height = i.height * 2});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'),function(i){i.style['background-size'] = '200% Auto'; });
```

Comment: No, I don't get the idea – as I said, I don't know javascript, much less jquery. And yes, those images are also links. This here is a work-safe part of 4chan, if you need to check anything else: http://boards.4chan.org/g/

Comment: Well, I just discovered that 4chan is totally blocked in my intranet.

Comment: ok, check my update code. Use your snippet in addition to my snippet. It should work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. One change that happened on this here page we're on is that now the image in my OP has doubled in length. The stackoverflow logo at the top is still the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that even a CSS solution would work for you (from your question). If there is no restriction on having real DOM width and height, you can also go for CSS transforms.

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2,2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2,2);
    /* etc. */
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript try:

```
for (i=0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    document.images[i].height *= 2;
    document.images[i].width *= 2; 
}
```

Comment: This is just another way to do it... Also, using the images is bad practice because images is a live "array".

Comment: This has the same effect as above, the gravatar logos are doubled, but nothing else…

Comment: Also OP's code is more concise. But beauty lies in the eye of beholder. So its relative concept.